# create array for store data from url

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want store 4 name of book from url (.php?info=1&**b=1** display name of first book) in array and run that code and use these names.

also I want create object of class and dedicate first name to first object (second name to second object and etc)

this is my code:

```
#import "Recipe.h"


for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        Recipe *booki = [Recipe new];    // create object
        NSLog(@"%d,%@",i,booki);

        NSString *c = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.102:81/temp/book.php?info=1&b=%d",i]]];

        NSMutableArray *b = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [b addObject:c];

        NSLog(@"%@,%@",c,b);

        booki.name = [NSString stringWithString:c];

        recipes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
        //NSLog(@"%@",recipes);
        recipes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:booki, nil];
```

in this code I see only one name in object and its last name of book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be this.

> recipes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:si, nil];

Since you are looping inside a for loop. If you want to have all names. You need to create an array outside the for loop. Instead of creating a new array each time add object to it.

```
if(!recipes){
   recipes = [NSMutableArray array];
}
[recipes addObject:si];
```

Comment: @mamalmamali My suggested code should be used inside the loop. But you need to keep an instance variable for holding recipes.